# How to reformat scraped table/data and export to CSV using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, export-to-csv

So far I've created a script that scrapes data (specifically a table) from a website. The problem is that the table/data is pre-formatted (surrounded by only the '< pre >' and '< /pre >' tags) and therefore I can't format the data the way I want. When I export to CSV, all the data is stored in one cell (A1). I've spent a couple hours looking at other resources but they only explain how to scrape and export data with other tags such as < class >, < div >, etc, and therefore they can separate headers from the rest of the data. Is there a way to reformat the table so that I can properly export it into CSV? Thanks!

Here is what I have so far (fake URL):

```
# import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, csv

# input query (format must be: yyyy, m, d; e.g.: 2017, 1, 31 for January 1 2017)
print("Choose your date (format must be: yyyy, m, d)")
year = input("Year: ")
month = input("Month: ")
day = input("Day: ")

# URL of web page + year, month, and day inputs
address = 'http://fakewebsite.statistics.phtml?y=%s&m=%s&d=%s' % (year, month, day)

# read web page
response = urllib.request.urlopen(address)
html = response.read()

# parse HTML code to find pre tags
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("pre").find(text=True)

with open ('output.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([table])

# print table to Python Shell
print(table)
```

This is what the output looks like in the Shell:

```
MONTHLY POOP STOOL STATISTICS ABSTRACT FOR: MONTH DAY, YEAR

 SEWER 1
SOMETHING ID    AAA | BBBB | DDDD  RRRRRRRR     OK          WILD      AIRAEMP     PRE   WAIGHT   STEMP
            #  |   %  |   %     # |  %      # |  %      # |  %      # |  %      # |  %      # |  %      # |  %
-------    -----------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
 #####      13 |  0.3 | 98.3   29 |  3.9  702 | 94.4  729 | 99.7  723 | 98.9  719 | 98.4  702 | 96.0  707 | 96.7
 #####     744 |    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0
 #####       7 |  0.1 | 99.1   21 |  2.8  716 | 96.2  732 | 99.3  727 | 98.6  725 | 98.4  716 | 97.2  719 | 97.6
 #####     744 |    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0
 #####     708 |    0 |  4.8    0 |    0   36 |  4.8   36 |  100   36 |  100   36 |  100   36 |  100   36 |  100
 #####     744 |    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0
 #####      18 |  0.1 | 97.6   28 |  3.8  698 | 93.8  721 | 99.3  713 | 98.2  708 | 97.5  698 | 96.1  699 | 96.3
 #####     744 |    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0
 #####     744 |    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0
 #####     744 |    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0
 #####     744 |    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0
 #####       5 |  0.1 | 99.3    7 |  0.9  732 | 98.4  738 | 99.9  737 | 99.7  737 | 99.7  732 | 99.1  733 | 99.2
 #####     744 |    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0    0 |    0
 #####      12 |  0.1 | 98.4   21 |  2.8  711 | 95.6  722 | 98.6  727 | 99.3  726 | 99.2  718 | 98.1  722 | 98.6
```